# Django 'validate' command not available

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and following djangobook tutorials, I came up with new error today which was very absurd i.e. whenever I run `python manage.py validate` it's shows an error:

> Unknown command: 'validate' Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

And, when I type `python manage.py help` i don't see validate under [django] title.
And yes, my python version is 2.7 and django version is 1.9.4.

Comment: This command does not exist, where did you find this command? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: "validate" has been deprecated in favor of "check" in Django 1.9.x version

Comment: The validate command checks whether your models’ syntax and logic are correct.if all went well i will see _italic_ 0 error found _italic_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Javier Clavero commented 'validate' has been deprecated in the favor of 'check' which i confirmed from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#deprecated-features-1-9), 10th from the bottom i thought it will be listed under model title, but chuck. Now i'm using **'python manage.py check'** in place of validate.